# is it possible to override the legacy app when install using brew

Tags: homebrew

I am using this command to install app in macOS Monterey(the apple M1 pro chip), but facing a problem like this:

```
➜  ~ brew install --cask dbeaver-community
==> Downloading https://dbeaver.io/files/21.3.2/dbeaver-ce-21.3.2-macos-aarch64.dmg
Already downloaded: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/c4fed662e860fd6ca0099f59da082b651e219af2b3369c1f85363dbc7469d1f2--dbeaver-ce-21.3.2-macos-aarch64.dmg
==> Installing Cask dbeaver-community
==> Purging files for version 21.3.2 of Cask dbeaver-community
Error: It seems there is already an App at '/Applications/DBeaver.app'.
```

is it possible to override the old app using homebrew but keep the old app config?

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /Applications/DBeaver.app` should solve this.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

using this command fix it:

```
➜  ~ brew install --cask dbeaver-community --force
==> Downloading https://dbeaver.io/files/21.3.2/dbeaver-ce-21.3.2-macos-aarch64.dmg
Already downloaded: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/c4fed662e860fd6ca0099f59da082b651e219af2b3369c1f85363dbc7469d1f2--dbeaver-ce-21.3.2-macos-aarch64.dmg
==> Installing Cask dbeaver-community
Warning: It seems there is already an App at '/Applications/DBeaver.app'; overwriting.
==> Removing App '/Applications/DBeaver.app'
==> Moving App 'DBeaver.app' to '/Applications/DBeaver.app'
  dbeaver-community was successfully installed!
```

Comment: `--force` doesn't work for me and it is still failing with error that this or that binary file already exists. I kept deleting them but there are many of them. `--overwrite` doesn't work with `--cask`

Comment: Works, but less than ideal. It forcibly downloads and installs the package *every time* even of the latest version from the cask is already installed. Ideally `--overwrite` would work with `--cask` but these options are not compatible with each other.

Answer (score 2):

Repeating the following commands resolved the issue for me:

```
brew outdated
brew reinstall foo
```

2 wild output appeared:

```
Warning: It seems there is already an App at '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/foo/21.3.2/foo.app'; overwriting.
```

and

```
Error: bar: Directory not empty @ dir_s_rmdir - /Applications/Bar.app
```

The wild Warning ran, so I could ignore it. But against the Error I had to fight. I figured, that the brew user did not have write permissions in a [multi-user brew setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41840479/how-to-use-homebrew-on-a-multi-user-macos-sierra-setup) on that file. Deleting the file (with `sudo` or as a user or group member with write permissions) and then using `brew reinstall` led to get away safely from that Error.

Alternatively, one could probably change the owner of that file with the `sudo` and `chown` command and execute `brew reinstall` or `brew install --force`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the flag `--force`. This suggestion comes from an answer to the problem on the official Homebrew GitHub page.

`brew remove --force --cask <CASK_NAME>`

Here's the actual result of my Google Chrome upgrade.

```
$ brew install --cask google-chrome --force

==> Upgrading 1 outdated package:
google-chrome 112.0.5615.49 -> 121.0.6167.160
==> Upgrading google-chrome
==> Downloading https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/universal/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg
Already downloaded: /Users/hassaan/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/88881e66883c4776fff9b3019b48a26795020439a33ddbedd3bd4620283aecd2--googlechrome.dmg
Warning: No checksum defined for cask 'google-chrome', skipping verification.
Warning: It seems there is already an App at '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/google-chrome/112.0.5615.49/Google Chrome.app'; overwriting.
==> Removing App '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/google-chrome/112.0.5615.49/Google Chrome.app'
==> Backing App 'Google Chrome.app' up to '/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/google-chrome/112.0.5615.49/Google Chrome.app'
==> Removing App '/Applications/Google Chrome.app'
==> Moving App 'Google Chrome.app' to '/Applications/Google Chrome.app'
==> Purging files for version 112.0.5615.49 of Cask google-chrome
  google-chrome was successfully upgraded!
```

Comment: How does this differ from the accepted answer?

Comment: @nohillside , the comment by `xbmono` is quite confusing. I'm adding this response along with logs of the `--force` flag to clarify the confusion."